# what is the difference between rsync --verbose versus -v

Tags: rsync

[Rsync helper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sujR6.png)

What's the difference between -v and --verbose flags for rsync? can I just use  --verbose without -v?

Comment: As the documentation says, they are **precisely** the same thing. Also, how is this a question about software development?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Alright Thank you. I'll just tag it as rsync instead of putting in all the others. 

I am curious why they have this -v and --verbose together if they are the same thing. No need to repeat the same thing right?

Comment: It's a GNU convention to have both short and long forms for flags. The short form is terse, the long form is readable. Though if you saw someone putting both on the same command line, yes, they could have just made it `-vv` (for `-v` / `--verbose`, specifying it more than once means "very verbose"; for some programs, three times or more increase verbosity still further) and been done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--verbose and -v are the same thing, -v stands for verbose. It's convention that the -v flag means verbose.